# std does not contain, but it should as have added the library

Tags: c++

Hi guys I am just starting to use C++ and I have a problem when I run this short code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::cout << std::legendre(3, 0.25);
}
```

I get that std does not contain legendre, but I am fairly sure it is in cmath. Can someone give advice?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++17?

Comment: Are you setting the C++17 flag when compiling?

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e70d82e959d04112 Works

Comment: There are some notes on availability here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/legendre

Comment: I am not sure what C++17 is, I am using code blocks as a compiler. Also I am sure the example compiles in general I do not know why it does not compile on my machine

Comment: @Gidy C++17 is a version of C++ (dating from 2017). Some compilers don't support it, some support it partially, some support it, but it must be explicitly enabled. etc. etc. Code blocks is not a compiler, it's an IDE which can use various compilers. You need to find out which compiler you are actually using and what it's support for C++17 is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code Blocks is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). The compiler is integrated but it's from third party. AFAIK, Code Blocks is shipped with g++ (GNU C++ compiler). You may call `g++ --version` to find out which exact version is used. You also have the option to replace it with a newer version. C++17 is the C++ standard. Please, search by google which g++ version supports which C++ standard. (The newer ones do quite well for C++17, and partly even for C++20 which is still in development.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::legendre` was introduced in C++ since C++17. gcc compiles your code with no problem since version 7, clang since version 5 and MSVC since preview 2018 https://godbolt.org/z/reoiaD

You need to enable C++17 with `-std=c++17` and possibly update your compiler.